# Struggling with typing an object, with computed property keys

Tags: javascript, typescript, computed-properties

I'm struggling to correctly type the `endpointMeta` object in my project.
It contains computed object keys that are related to 2 objects

1. `services` - contains the names of the services currently known. The number of services may increase later.
2. `endpoints` - define the endpoints available in the service, that are being called in the project.

```
enum services {
    serviceNameOne = 'service1',
    serviceNameTwo = 'service2',
    serviceNameThree = 'service3',
};


const endpoints = {
    [services.serviceNameOne]: {
        getUser: '/getUser',
        verifyDetails: '/s/verifyDetails',
    },
    [services.serviceNameTwo]: {
        fetchCustomersv1: '/v1/fetchCustomers',
        fetchCustomersv2: '/v2/fetchCustomersv1',
    },
    [services.serviceNameThree]: {
        getAllProjects: '/g/a/p',
        getProject: '/g/p',
        updateProject: '/u/p',
    }
}
```

`endpointMeta` - object contains some meta info about these endpoints

```
const endpointMeta = {
    [services.serviceNameOne]:{
        [endpoints.serviceOne.getUser]: {
            description: 'something about getUser',
            version: 1
        },
        [endpoints.serviceOne.verifyDetails]:{
            description: 'something about verifyDetails',
            version: 3
        },
    },
    [services.serviceNameTwo]:{
        [endpoints.serviceTwo.fetchCustomersv1]: {
            description: 'something about fetchCustomersv1',
            version: 1
        },
        [endpoints.serviceTwo.fetchCustomersv1]:{ // duplicate object :(
            description: 'something about fetchCustomersv1',
            version: 1
        },
    }

}
```

**Edit**

What I ideally want is for when other devs are introducing new services or endpoints, they should be forced to add an entry to the `endpointmeta` object.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=69&ssc=1&pln=46&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAzsBOA3AlgY2DKBvAsAKCkNgRXQDkBDCYAeRGCgF4oByOJNW+lgGnyOIdyVYABUA7gHsmrdqTFTe-InM6VqogBbxgDZmxKctO4ErwBfANz58AeltQALgE8ADg1EBlQ+kzMA1sDOkgBmTm7AoYLyMNZ4Nnj24e5QogCiIAAmrpLIII4yuIkOAgDagc5QeaneQhhQFJgABqWqvgB0ACRYFeYAuk19AFzYdiUCROVBAEwjMI7weQDmwxQgzmMT5pvb8cXJHhnZufnThZtlbRjtV+pcwMNQAErAqJLwmQA884sgSzw-ZYAPh2CQSbxA8ygoGOeUcflGBEmVxgNx8wDudAeIyKEyIS2AjgAquwRixbATiewzHjCIgEMgQs4ACKEijIAA2MDJthgtnpiyZrMc7K5NKI5j4SMIrXRqNuIgkkkeuNpIUJqE0AGEwPNJNR4DBEABGHkm2zqxyanV6g0wcV4y3W3WOfUII2zVj86YWjXal1uw0mh1QSXKGUotF1O7GXQq8MTSkAQQ5HIACvBJAArV7wnlLWwUWyuEMCSkZ7O5-PF0tEMCuTIURzACs51COHlgGtSgS7XabFwpJYyNIADwWFHbn0HkTCMJycJgPFgC2BYL2SRnqSOC-yAFk2ed9mV-FUQDU5Y8wCB-CBJOIQKC9hCofOTo4DyKj5c5VH5Jj6GGVU8VKN9Fz-TgsXaSkSQQeNpVpQhMgwVBFlcRxkEkEAyRgN1HE0ZYGgAI0kMAChg6ke0QogBRgTDsKgY0E17KiQLA-J5XRKCBUZFk2U5GAgOY2lkJgVDkHQ+icLwgi-mI0iCh4oV+LFVjqNoqSoAAZmEwgwwQ-SfzqTjo0VKQhIQsp2PhCD0CVdonX9W13RNeDqKIUTxMkrDpOofDCIoEiyKgRybVdO1gzUxCNJ8xjdNDKLJmskz5Hs0KAwi40gKgJJMnrDk0CbBhJCItsCiGAAKeKBE8tCMNitgZICoKCnS5yg2NWs8RihimMsiU1P7Cx8CAA)

Comment: Your question is a little unclear, but I think [this github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25758) outlines some context around what you're seeing.

Comment: What, specifically, is your question?  If you want strong typings I'd say you should let the compiler tell them to you via inference, maybe with a `const` assertion or two to give the hint that it should care about the string literal values, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wQY2Vw).  If you want the compiler to catch the duplicate property, then you run into the bug at ms/TS#25758.  Could you [edit] to make it very clear what specific single question you're asking?

Comment: Oh, I really missed what I really want to solve. What I ideally want is for when other devs are introducing new services or endpoints, TS should force them to add an entry to the `endpointmeta ` object.

Comment: So then does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mL53kW) meet your needs? It uses the new [`satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) to enforce the constraints you're talking about.  Please test it; if it works for you I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (If you reply, please mention @jcalz in your comment; otherwise I will not be notified)